# Select Database name based on Source Folder at run time in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I came across through one complicated situation in SSIS. 
I need to access 10 Folders which contains .txt files: \Root\Customer 1.txt files (File name and schema are same in all folders) and that should load in different databases. to achieve this, i am using For Each Loop and inside Foreach using Execute package tasks to point each file to the corresponding pacakge.

For Instance, From the \Root Folder if i am processing 'Customer 1' Folder files these data should be loaded into Customer 1 database.

i.e if folder is \Customer 2 --> Customer 2 DB
    if folder is \Customer 3 --> Customer 3 DB and vice versa.
So, as soon as my SSIS selected Customer 1 folder target Database should be set to Customer 1 DB.

Here i am stucked with selecting database name based on customer folder .

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "expressions" in the connection manager which then substitute into server/database.

In you case it folder name on which for each container is working .

Note: donot  forget evaluate expression to true.